# How to add URI record to bind9 DNS zone?

Tags: dns, bind9

I want to setup my Kerberos authentication using DNS lookups to define its servers. This can be done with URI records in the DNS database. There is given an example for [KDC Discovery](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/realm_config.html?highlight=dns_uri_lookup#kdc-discovery) that looks like:

```
_kerberos.EXAMPLE.COM  URI  10 1 krb5srv:m:tcp:kdc1.example.com
```

Now I try to add this record to the DNS database with `nsupdate`:

```
~$ sudo nsupdate
> update add _kerberos.EXAMPLE.COM  URI  10 1 krb5srv:m:tcp:kdc1.example.com
ttl 'URI': not a valid number
>
```

Doesn't work this way. What is the command to add the URI record? Is there another way to add the record to the DNS database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `nsupdate` to add a record, you must specify a Time-To-Live value (TTL) for it to specify the maximum time the record can be cached by any resolver DNS server before querying an authoritative DNS server for an up-to-date version of the record again. This is true for all record types. The TTL value goes in between the name and the record type.

If you wanted to specify a TTL of 7200 seconds (2 hours), for example:

```
$ sudo nsupdate
> update add _kerberos.EXAMPLE.COM  7200 URI  10 1 "krb5srv:m:tcp:kdc1.example.com"
```

Please also note the double quotes around the string.

If your nearest DNS server is the authoritative one for your DNS zone, and the record is used locally only, then the TTL value might not be very important, but it still needs to be specified.

Comment: It didn't work on the first attempt but the error message gave me the hint. the string at the end needs double quotes. I was so free to edit your answer.